# How to set Grafana monitoring on dynamic pod name

Tags: alert, grafana

I have one dashboard that monitoring all pod using Grafana stored variable, looks like this image below

[image: grafana varibale]

I want to set alert on each panel (CPU and Memory) time series, but it can't resolve the variable name on query and showing `no data` issues. I have to put the exact name of pod, so the query would run gracefully.

the `no data` issue would look like this

[image: grafana issue]

Is it possible running the alert with one dashboard in the same panel (depends on pod variable name we use)? any suggestions?